# The original function value after it has been redefined by decorator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, decorator, redefine

In decorator patterns, the original function may be redefined like this: `original = wrapper(original)`. Why does `wrapper2` in the example below use the original `aa` function (a + b), if it has been redefined by the`wrapper` function before (a + b + 12)?

```js
function aa(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
console.log(aa)       //function aa(a,b) {return a+b}
console.log(aa(1, 2)) //3


function wrapper(fn) {
  return function() {
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1] + 12
  }
}
aa = wrapper(aa)
console.log(aa)       //function(){return arguments[0]+arguments[1]+12}
console.log(aa(1, 2)) //15


function wrapper2(fn) {
  return function() {
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1] + 120
  }
}
aa = wrapper2(aa)
console.log(aa)       //function(){return arguments[0]+arguments[1]+120}
console.log(aa(1, 2)) //123
```

Comment: it's wrapping 120 instead of 12. would be nice if you could just curry in the third value instead of hard-coding it...

Comment: You never use `fn`, so you arent really wrapping the previous `aa` functions. All you are doing is defining a function that will return a function that will add the first two arguments and adding a third hard coded value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using *fn* at all.
Try this one:

```
function wrapper(fn) {
  return function() {
    return ( fn( arguments[0], arguments[1] ) + 12 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think there's one extra parenthesis in your code though.